# Unexpected behavior when using state monad - State wrapped in a list

Tags: haskell, state, state-monad, io-monad

I am learning Haskell now, and I am trying to work with the state Monad.

I am recursively asking for input from the user and append it to the list. When I am implementing the IO handling and state execution in the same function, the program works as expected:

```
import Control.Monad.State

push :: String -> State [String] ()
push a = state $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)


testingState :: State [String] ()
testingState = do
  push ("testing state!")
  return ()


handleState :: [String]  -> IO()
handleState previousStack = do
  line <- getLine
  let userIntput = words line
  let stack = userIntput ++ previousStack
  let newStack = (execState testingState) stack
  handleState newStack


main :: IO 
main = do
  handleState []
```

For reasons I don't understand, when I am separating the state handling function from the IO function, the returned state is wrapped with a list:

```
handleState :: [String]  -> IO()
handleState previousStack = do
  line <- getLine
  let newStack = changeState line stack
  handleState newStack

changeState :: String -> [String] -> [String]
changeState line previousStack = do
  let userIntput = words line
  let stack = userIntput ++ previousStack
  let newStack = (execState testingState) stack
  return newStack


main = do
  handleState []
```

The following code gives me a compiler error that the actually returned type is a nested list:

```
  • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
  Expected type: [String]
    Actual type: [[String]]
```

Also, I can only flatten the array outside of `changeState` function, doing it inside the function would not work.

Anyone could explain why this is happening? and a better way of handling state in a recursive function?

Comment: You don't use an `IO` in `changeState`. So that means you use a `Monad []`, and `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` will wrap an element in a list for the list instance of `Monad`.

Comment: We have `newStack :: [String]` hence `return newState :: [[String]]` has the wrong type. Don't use `do`, `return` if you do not intend to work inside some monad. Or, perhaps, you wanted to write a more general IO version of your `changeState`? Hard to tell.

Comment: The minimal change that makes this work is to simply delete `return`. The `return` function actually does computation in Haskell, unlike the `return` keyword in most languages that have one.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `do` in and `return` in the `changeState`. Since the type of the `do` block is `[String]`, it will make use of a the list instance of the `Monad` typeclass, and this thus means that `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` will wrap an element in a list.

You can implement you `changeState` function as:

```
changeState :: String -> [String] -> [String]
changeState line previousStack = execState testingState (words line ++ previousStack)
```